# FAB transparent layer does not block the parent layer

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have a problem using [Clans FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton). I need to add a transparent layer that blocks the parent layer. The effect that I need is similar to Google Inbox. 
So in my example I have this sequence:
1) Click item 3

[image]

2) Click on fab

[image]

3) When I click over transparent layer, the item from ListView is clicked.

[image]

I try to block the click event transparent layer using:

```
final FloatingActionMenu menu1 = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.menu1);
menu1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        menu1.close(true);
    }
});
```

So with this code, when I click transparent layer the fab menu is closed (this is ok), but the same click listener blocking the click event over listView.
I have tried different ways to solve this problem but the only way I found was to resize the background programmatically . This is not a good solution because the effect is not good.

In a few hours I'll upload a demo and source code to github , but even as hope someone can help me with some idea. Thank You

**EDITED**

- Here is the [LINK to my repo](https://github.com/gastoncesarf/Fab-example).
- Here is the [LINK to download this apk](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxNgay9IsYFfT3hPbVVaR01ZbEU/view?usp=sharing)
- Here is the [LINK to video demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxNgay9IsYFfUndqaW1LbUVsbTA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: i do not really get you sir, your click listeners are block when the fab pops up?

Comment: When the fab is clicked, the fab menu is opened, so fab buttons are displayed and the transparent layer, and when I click over this layer, actually, the click is made on the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have download your project from Github and tried the code myself and have solved the issue.

It is working perfectly for me as demonstrated in the Inbox by Google app. You just need to change a very small portion of your code.

```
menu1.setOnMenuToggleListener(new FloatingActionMenu.OnMenuToggleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuToggle(boolean opened) {
                if (opened) {
                    menu1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            menu1.close(true);
                            menu1.setClickable(false);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Close", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
```

Hope I could help you.

Comment: Thanks but not working, the fab menu layer is blocking the click event over the listview. Please, if you can, try to see the effect in [Inbox App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.inbox), i need the same effect on my fab. Sorry for my english, maybe I'm not explaining the problem properly.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I have told you. I have also done the same thing in one of my apps. Please post your code where you have made the changes I have told you.

Comment: Please see this [link to my github repo](https://github.com/gastoncesarf/Fab-example). Also I have edited my post. Thanks

Comment: In that code, I did not put the code you provided me , but I tried and not worked. Blocks click on the parent layer but when the "FAB menu" is closed , click on the list view is not working.

Comment: Glad that I could help you.